# When to explicitly set objects to null in order to make the memory reclaimable in Java?

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection

I found the following in the book that I use to learn Java:

The garbage collector only frees memory that is allocated using `new`. But it has no knowledge of memory that is allocated using other methods. So, the gc cannot reclaim it. An example of such memory allocation would be native methods in Java.

I don't have the exact wording right now but the book has something like that when it explains Objects in detail. The book only provides a single example of such a case where GC can't reclaim memory for us. I am sure there are other situations when this happens. Can someone please list some of them as that would help us know when to set objects to null, explicitly and when it is okay to rely on GC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much everything other than primitives and Strings are instantiated with a `new`. And you should not be worried about Garbage collection to the extent that you have to set variables to `null` to make them eligible. GC has become very intelligent in last few years that we don't have to resort these tricks. e.g. Any orphaned object in heap ( which is not referred by anything) is a GC candidate. If you have your code structured, all method scope objects are GC candidate once the method has finished execution, same with a state variable as soon as the object of the class itself is dereferenced.

Comment: So does that means the overhead of setting objects to null is completely removed?

Comment: @Devashish pretty much!

Comment: @Devashish That over head is not completely removed. Check out the source code for `ArrayList.remove` That is written in Java. They use an array under the hood and use this line: `elementData[--size] = null; // clear to let GC do its work`

Answer (score -1):

First you should not worry about native methods unless you are the author of them. 
The only time that you need to null out references is when you are doing your own memory management. 
Consider that you are writing your own data-structure, a stack for instance that uses an array as the underlying structure. Add some elements to the stack. Now pop the stack and hand off an element without nulling out the reference in the array. There will be a potentially unused, "obsolete" reference in the stack. This reference still points onto the heap and it is not eligible for GC. 
Check out item 6 in Joshua Bloch's "Effective Java", this exact example is outlined there.

Comment: isn't poping from a stack means removing it from stack as well? That one simply means you have bad code, at which point you should be more concerned about application behavior than GC.

Comment: Yes, in order to remove from the underlying array, the reference must be nulled out. If the application using the stack no longer keeps a reference to the element, the stack will if it is not properly removed, ie. explicitly set to null. This is an example of when to explicitly set a reference to null in order to make memory reclaimable by GC.

Comment: Isn't it wrong stack implementation at that point?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)

Comment: After the elements are properly nulled out it is not a wrong implementation by any means. It is just proof that there can be, and are instances that references need to be nulled out to avoid memory leaks. GC is great but when doing your own memory management, care should be taken. Thanks!